# How do I determine the value of a resistor in series with an LED without knowing V source?

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, led, resistance

Is the voltage drop across the resistor also 1.7 V? This is probably a trick question, but the schematic given is as follows:

[image]

Vcc isn't given, so would the series resistance just be 170 Ω?

Comment: More information is required.  You simply cannot determine the resistor value without knowing the source voltage.

Comment: Without knowing the value of VCC, the best you can do is to write an equation for R in terms of VCC, VD, and the diode current.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\$V_{cc}\$ is equal to the voltage drop across the LED plus the voltage drop across the resistor (the latter calculated using Ohm's law):

$$V_{cc}=1.7~\mathrm{V}+10~\mathrm{mA}\cdot R\implies\\R=\frac{V_{cc}-1.7}{0.01}$$

You need to know \$\small V_{cc}\$ to find the value of \$\small R\$. Without knowing \$\small V_{cc}\$ you can only answer with an equation.

Answer (score 3):

A question such as this one would typically expect an answer that is an **equation** determining R as a function of Vcc. You should also be able to write down the range of validity of the equation (in terms of allowable Vcc values).

Bonus points for understanding about in what Vcc range the equation becomes dodgy since things are not black and white in the real world.

Comment: I would not imagine a problem like that assumes we start talking about cooking the LED or resistor or Vf versus current/temperature, though.

Comment: @Barleyman maybe that's why it's *bonus* points. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn about Ohm's Law and calculate it like this:

You **must** know V<sub>CC</sub> to calculate the resistance using Ohm's Law.

\$ {{3.0~\mathrm{V}- 1.7~\mathrm{V}}\over{10~\mathrm{mA}}} = {{1.30~\mathrm{V}}\over{10~\mathrm{mA}}}= 130~Ω\$

\$ {{12~\mathrm{V} - 1.7~\mathrm{V}}\over{10~\mathrm{mA}}} = {{10.3~\mathrm{V}}\over{10~\mathrm{mA}}} = 1030~Ω\$

\$ {{48~\mathrm{V} - 1.7~\mathrm{V}}\over{10~\mathrm{mA}}} = {{46.3~\mathrm{V}}\over{10~\mathrm{mA}}} = 4630~Ω\$

Comment: Audioguru - Hi, I saw your (deleted) post, so let me help: To force a line break on this site's editor, add 2x spaces at the end of a line. This site uses "Markdown" syntax (with optional MathJax) and if you just press enter at the end of a line then, as you saw, that does not cause a line break like it would in a classic text editor. Here is the [editing help page](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/editing-help) which mentions the 2x spaces at EOL for line breaks, with other useful info. Hope that helps. (Please reply in a comment when you've copied that link & I'll delete this. Thanks.)

Comment: @SamGibson How did you navigate to the /editing-help website? I was looking for such website on electronics.stackexchange but could not find it. I think the /editing-help should be placed in a visible and easy to reach spot like under /help or in /tour.

Comment: @ChristianidisVasileios - Hi, Glad it was useful. "*I think the /editing-help should be placed in a visible and easy to reach spot like under /help*" Valid point. It's not on the front page, but it is there. Navigate via: [Help] -> Our model -> View more -> (direct link to here is [this](/help/stackexchange)) -> "[How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](/help/formatting)" -> 2nd paragraph link to "[advanced editing help page](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/editing-help)".

Comment: (continued) As this isn't something specific to EE, please consider raising on Meta.SE if your specific request doesn't already exist. See existing "editing-help" tagged questions here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/editing-help - I expect that would be a suitable tag (along with "feature-request" probably) if you want a specific link to be added somewhere to reach that [editing-help](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/editing-help) page. Thanks.